# Switch case to check ViewControllers conform to protocol

Tags: swift, switch-statement, protocols

I have a protocol...

```
protocol MyProtocol {}
```

And some of my view controllers conform to this protocol...

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyProtocol {}
```

And some of them don't...

```
class OtherViewController: UIViewController {}
```

Now... I have a function which takes two `UIViewController` types. Depending on what types they are I need to do different things.

So I have a switch. In that switch I sometimes need to check the specific types and sometimes I need to check the protocol conformance.

```
switch (firstVC, secondVC) {
case is (MyViewController, OtherViewController):
    // do something this works
case is (OtherViewController, MyViewController):
    // do something else this works
case is (MyProtocol, MyProtocol):
    // this breaks...
}
```

The error that I get is...

> Cast from (UIViewController, UIViewController) to unrelated type (MyProtocol, MyProtocol) always fails

But I know that not to be the case.

How can I check for the conformance of the `UIViewControllers` to my protocol?

Thanks

Comment: What about `case let(first as MyProtocol, second as MyProtocol):` ?

Comment: @MartinR I could've sworn that I tried that already! Haha :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reson for the error is that you cannot cast a tuple to anything, especially not member-wise.

You could use case-let:

```
switch (firstVC, secondVC) {
    case (let mvc as MyViewController, let ovc as OtherViewController):
        // do something with mvc and ovc
    case (let ovc as OtherViewController, let mvc as MyViewController):
        // do something else
    case (let m1 as MyProtocol, let m2 as MyProtocol):
        // this breaks...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per `@MartinR` comment.

I can use...

```
case let (_ as MyProtocol, _ as MyProtocol):
```

Could've sworn I had tried that before.

In fact I needed to do a bit more checking in my case and so I did this...

```
case let (a as MyProtocol, _ as MyProtocol) where !(a is MyViewController):
```

Or something along those lines anyway.

Comment: If you don't need to bind to a variable, you can also say `is MyProtocol` instead of `_ as MyProtocol`.

Comment: @Hamish that’s what I was doing that was causing the error. :-)

Comment: You only get that warning for tuples though, not individual `is` checks. Though in any case, looks like it's an incorrect warning as the runtime check succeeds.